# Do we need to send HSync, Vsync, HFP, VFP, HACTIVE in the Display port

Tags: display, port

On going through the display port specification, in the main stream packet structure I see only the pixels getting packed between blanking start and blanking end. Don't we need to send HFP, HBP, Hsync, Vsync that is done in DSI transfer.
How DP take care of this? Don't we need to transfer that information? Is it sufficient only to send pixel data?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for this further in the spec. This information is transferred in Vertical blanking period between SS and SE (Secondary symbol)